# Getting "boot error" when trying to boot from USB

Tags: boot, usb, dell, inspiron

I'm wanting to try out Ubuntu, so followed the instructions for how to install Ubuntu onto a USB. I downloaded the .iso file, then the pendrivelinux 3 part process to make the USB bootable.

I can see what looks like a full list of files on the USB (including the wubi.exe application and the syslinux folder).

When I try to restart the computer with the USB in, I get the Dell start up screen, and then a black screen with "Boot Error" in the top right hand corner.

Setup options (default) are to boot from Removable Device, then Hard Disc. USB is brand new, straight out of the packet.

Computer: Dell Inspiron 530S
BIOS: 1.0.13
OS: Windows Vista Home Edition
USB: EMTEC 8Gb, formatted to FAT32

I've tried some of the tips in other help topics (holding down CTRL key while restarting, removing all other USB devices). I tried to reformat the USB to something other than FAT32, but my only other options were NTFS or exFAT (not FAT16 which was suggested in another topic).

Comment: I'm beginning to think the issue is my BIOS. I've found some stuff on the internet (http://forums.bodhilinux.com/index.php?/topic/3544-solved-usb-flash-boot-fails-on-dell-ok-on-netbook/) about Dell 530's. The Dell 530 views my USB as a USB-ZIP, and I think it needs to see it as a USB-HDD before it will allow me to boot from it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of trouble creating an actual bootable USB. Hope this helps someone avoid the same trouble I had ...

I found this hint online somewhere and thought I'd share:

Get the **mbr** software

```
apt-get install mbr
```

Install a boot sector onto the USB

```
sudo install-mbr /dev/sdd
```

Copy an iso image onto the device

```
sudo dd if=ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdd
```

*replace `/dev/sdd` with your own device.*

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Yesss! This one worked for me...none of the others did. Looks like unetbootin and other GUIs are adding too much to the USB. For installation on older computers it may be that the commandline method works better.

Answer (score 0):

Your USB disk isn't prepared properly.

Try some othe programs to create bootable USB.

- [LILI](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/help/guide/using-lili)
- [UnetbootIN](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Also make sure, this USB is the first bootable disk. In newer dell you can press <kbd>F12</kbd> after starting the system to choose from which device you need to boot.

Comment: Thanks. I've re-done the USB with UnetbootIN, but still getting the same response. I'll try LILI as well. I've checked startup set-up using F12, and it is booting the USB first. It just seems to have an issue with the USB...

Comment: I took the USB around to a friends place, and we managed to boot Ubuntu from it. so I think it's okay. I'm now suspecting the issue is my PC.

Comment: have you tried changing your Bios  mode from legacy to UEFI ?

Answer (score 0):

At least with Vostro desktops, it seems to be a known problem:
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/p/19355577/19824583.aspx

http://commweb-ps3.us.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/f/3514/p/19030252/19158279.aspx

I posted what worked for me on both of those threads, but I'm not sure if it is applicable to the Inspiron too. You might try and post your results here

Comment: Can you copy your answer to those threads here?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "Boot Error" with usb bootable of Ubuntu 12.04. Then I repeated making the image again and tried in another machines then realized it's my machine problem.

There are a couple of posting about this issue but not helped.

I am not very sure what causes or 100% works this way. I just played around the usb setting in bios. Then it worked.

My way:

1. setting operational mode from high speed mode to full
2. usb mode from auto to hdd mode.

Hope this gives any hint for someone who can actually solve this issue.